How to correctly fetch Ollamas Streaming Response in Flutter?
I need to display the generated text from my Ollama Endpoint as it arrives.
When i call:
curl http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{
  "model": "llama3.1",
  "prompt": "Why is the sky blue?"
}'

Then i get one json response after the other with a little of time in between like that:
{"model":"dolphin-llama3","created_at":"2024-09-25T01:55:49.628815773Z","response":"The","done":false}

{"model":"dolphin-llama3","created_at":"2024-09-25T01:55:49.91987057Z","response":" sky","done":false}

{"model":"dolphin-llama3","created_at":"2024-09-25T01:55:50.210919534Z","response":" appears","done":false}

...


But when i try to get the same response in flutter using this code:
final request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(apiEndpoint + '/generate'))
        ..headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        ..body = json.encode({
          'model': 'dolphin-llama3',
          'prompt': message,
          'stream': true,
        });

      try {
        // Send the request and get the streamed response
        final streamedResponse = request.send().asStream().asyncExpand((response) => response.stream
            .transform(utf8.decoder)
            .transform(const LineSplitter()));

        // Initialize an empty string to collect the bot response
        String botResponse = '';

        await for (var jsonLine in streamedResponse) {
          // Parse each line of the stream as JSON
          final parsedJson = jsonDecode(jsonLine);

          if (parsedJson.containsKey('response')) {
            setState(() {
              botResponse += parsedJson['response'];
              _messages.last['message'] = botResponse;
            });
          }

          // If done, break out of stream.
          if (parsedJson['done'] == true) {
            break;
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
        // Optionally, add an error message to the chat if something goes wrong
        setState(() {
          _messages.add({
            'role': 'bot',
            'message': 'An error occurred while fetching the response.'
          });
        });
      }

All the messages are displayed at the same time when the last one would have arrived.
What would i need to change to display each word right after it arrives?
I expected the json responses to behave equally regardless whatever i use curl or the http library in dart/flutter.
